# Python tenacity library retry what does after & retry_error_callback do

Tags: python, retry-logic, tenacity

Using retry. What does after and retry_error_callback specifically do?

```
@retry(   stop=stop_after_attempt(3),  
          wait=wait_exponential(multiplier=3, max=3) + wait_random(0, retry_wait_jitter),  
          after=logger.error("Error"),  
          retry_error_callback=logger.error("Error"))
```

Comment: Is there documentation for the library?

Comment: could not find anything on these, https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=retry#

Answer (score 0):

after = execute after each retry
retry_error_callback = execute after all retries